# How to create a new factor based on a current factor?

Tags: r, r-factor

In `R`, I am trying to do is create a factor by "grouping" values in another factor or character string.

```
    factor1 <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","D"))
```

what I would like is to create a `factor2` such that `A` & `B` are `E` and `C` & `D` are `F`.  I've tried looping and can't get that to work but believe there has to be an elegant `R` way to do this.

Comment: Thank you Arun, based on your response I need to be more specific, apologies to all.  I have a vector (1 col x 2500 rows) whose contents can be any 1 of the 50 US states. I would like to create a factor variable based on this vector where I identify/flag a subset of 4 states (say CA, OR, WA, AK) as 1 and all others as 0.

Comment: Is there any reason to not simply add a new column with your flag?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, yes that was my suggestion as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
 library(car)
 fac2 <- recode( factor1, " c('A', 'B') = 'E';
                            c('C', 'D') = 'F' ")
 fac2

# [1] E E F F
Levels: E F
```

Note the need to keep track of two kinds of quotes and the need to use ";" between grouping clauses. There is also an 'else' argument that the help page for `?car::recode` will describe. For the amended question a `recode` strategy would work, but also this would succeed:

```
fac2 <- 0 + factor1 %in%  c('CA', 'OR', 'WA', 'AK')  # numeric result
fac2 <- factor(fac2) # factor result which displays like a character vector
```

Note that state.abb is effectively a system constant, although it is character vector rather than a factor:

```
 sts <- state.abb[sample(50)]   # a scrambled version
 sts[ sts %in% c('CA', 'OR', 'WA', 'AK')]
#[1] "CA" "AK" "OR" "WA"
```

For use of car::recode, this code succeeds (noting that `recode` returns a factor if given a factor as input, which I did not):

```
 recode(sts, " c('CA', 'OR', 'WA', 'AK') = 1; else=0")
#-------
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
[45] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: recode looks like what I need!  thanks.  I'll repost upon success.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more! Thanks for this function `recode`. One more useful function!

Comment: It's John Fox's code. It used to be almost a frequently asked question on Rhelp. I can only take credit for remember what John wrote.

Comment: recode did the trick.  Very helpful for regressing with factors when you want to group factors together within a factor. Great help!  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're expecting?

```
factor2 <- factor1
levels(factor2) <- rep(c("E","F"), each=2)

# [1] E E F F
# Levels: E F
```

Using @DWin's example, I'd do something like this:

```
set.seed(2)
sts <- state.abb[sample(50)]
# your factor1 would be
factor1 <- factor(sts)
# you would construct factor2 as 
factor2 <- factor(0 + factor1 %in% c('CA', 'OR', 'WA', 'AK'))
```

Comment: I Arun, thanks for the assist, I've modified my question a bit more,  I was not specific enough the first time.

Comment: @FrankShuster, The levels of factor will be equal to the number of unique elements in a vector. So, I don't think you can set a binary level to a vector with 50 unique values. Why not create a separate column setting those values that match these four values to `1` and others to `0`?

Comment: @FrankShuster, probably this edit using DWin's example does what you're after..?